# Bad Substitution Error with System command in C

Tags: c, bash, shell

I have written a C program with some system command in it. I use a software called Gromacs. Here is the snippet of C code :-

```
       #include<stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

      /*I have removed unnecessary code, which works fine for me. */   

      int main() {

            float LAMBDA=0.37;

            for(LAMBDA=0.37 ; LAMBDA <0.55; LAMBDA +=0.02 ) {

            system("g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh");
            system("mapfile -t a < <(g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh | sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//')");

            printf("Free Energy:\t ");
            system("echo ${a[120]}");

       return 0;
     }
```

I receive an error

```
      sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

I have checked previous answers on Bad substitution. It seems dash doesn't work with arrays then how can I enable Bash for system commands ? If somebody can troubleshoot me I will be grateful.

Comment: Do the shell commands run when issue in `sh` directly? Also which of the three commands issues the error?!

Comment: I think last system command with echo gives this error.

Comment: Add some debug statements to be sure, where to look for the cause.

Comment: I guess you are running on some POSIX system, probably Linux. Then you should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to learn a lot more about [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) creation and management with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and several other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). An answer won't be able to teach you all that; you need hours or days of reading

Comment: BTW, when you construct (at runtime) a command string for `system` or `popen` beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Answer (score 5):

The `sh` vs `dash` vs `bash` is not the root problem here.

You create a 'a' (whatever that is) in your second call to `system()`.

Then you try to use this 'a' in the forth `system()` call.

But this is *another shell*, and 'a' does not exist here.

Each time you call `system()`, a *new* shell environment is created, and disappear at return.

What you need to do is somehow save your 'a' to some file that a subsequent call may work on.

In other words, each call to `system()` act as if you opened a new terminal, do your stuff and then closed it. The variables created in one terminal (shell session) do not exist in the following one.

**EDIT:**

And to convince you that the `sh/dash/bash` is not your root problem here, once you've check your commands run OK when typed in the same shell session (terminal), you can always explicitly use `bash` in your `system()` calls by;

```
system("bash -c do_my_stuff from_this and_that etc");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `mapfile` is a bash 4 builtin command.  `system` runs `sh`, not `bash`.

Second, and the cause of the error message, you are using *process substitution* here:

```
<(g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh | sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//')
```

`sh` does not support process substitution.  `system` runs `sh`, not `bash`.

You have several calls to `system`.  Your last call (as shown) looks at a variable `a` that was created in a previous shell process, it won't exist anymore!

I suggest you write a bash script, complete with `#!/bin/bash`, and call that from C.  You could always write out the script from C, using `fopen` and `fprintf`.

If that isn't practical, the use `bash -c` as suggested by @jbm.  But you can't expect any persistence across calls to `system` except via the C program.